# Android: Filter Listview adapter in % searchstring % format

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Im using one edittext and listview in my app.
i need to display the list according to the text in edittext.

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
```

eg
if i type the value as "an" means it display like

Andorra

Angola

Antigua

But i need like this

Andorra

Angola

Antigua

Bangladesh

Bhutan

Canada

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/) is the example exactly which you are looking for. check this

Here is the simple logic with `` `Arrays `` and `addTextChangedListener` for `EditText`

In Change the block of code as like this.

```
if (textlength {
   if ((String)listview_array[i].contains(et.getText().toString()))
   {
     array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
   }
```

I have replace `equalsIgnorecase` with `contains`. Please check the difference here

Comment: this also works as same... searching from first character only

Comment: ya i saw and implement in that... but the searching happen like same only

Comment: Sorry there is small mistake in understanding. now check once again the edited answer

Comment: Great dude now its work fine... thanks a lot.. pls upvote for my question